# resteasy-client versioning and correspondance with server resteasy jar

Tags: jboss, resteasy

I am working with JBoss EAP 6.0.0 and it's using resteasy-jaxrs:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1 as a dependency on the server.

I am wondering what version of org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client I am supposed to use on the client side: the only stable versions available on maven repositories are from 3.0.0 onwards. I could add the same dependency than on the server side, but I'd like to import only what's necessary.

Where can I find a explanation of resteasy-client versioning in order to decide which version of the client to use?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two Resteasy versions is that the version 2.x implements JAX-RS 1.1 which is part of JEE6 and the version 3.x implements JAX-RS 2.0.

One of the key feature of JAX-RS 2.0 is the client API and it's part of JEE7.

To answer your question, you can find the information in the release note of the resteasy library (http://www.jboss.org/resteasy).

By the way, the version 2.x still comes with a minimal client framework which can be found as you mentioned in the org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs lib.